# Why some messages are not sent by Facebook chat API?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-chat

We've been running the Facebook Chat API on our app for months, but since recently we started to get 1 out of 5 messages that don't seem to be sent anymore.

For sending we use this:

```
sender_chat_id = "-#{uid}@chat.facebook.com"
    client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
    client.connect
    client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client,
                                                         app_id,
                                                         access_token,
                                                         app_secret]
                     ), nil)

    # Send messages

    client.send(jabber_message)

    # Close chat client
    client.close
```

and it seems to work. then we check if the message is sent with:

```
Fql.execute({
                 "query1" => "SELECT body FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id, recipients FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 1 AND #{receiver_uid} IN recipients ORDER BY updated_time DESC) ORDER BY created_time DESC"
             }, {
                 access_token: access_token
             })
```

And unfortunately sometimes the message just won't appear in the outbox.

EDIT:

The problem seems to come from messages sent to people that don't have a thread with the sender containing previous messages.
In those cases, the message sent by the Facebook chat API is not delivered. 
However when if the sender sends a message to the receiver (or vice versa) "manually", the thread is opened and all the messages sent before by the API appear...